# F# Pattern matching on a generic type Map

Tags: f#, pattern-matching

This works :

```
// sample objects    
let dctStrDbl = [("k1",1.0);  ("k2",2.0)]  |> Map.ofList
let dctStrStr = [("k1","v1"); ("k2","v2")] |> Map.ofList
let lstMisc   = [1; 2; 3]

let testStrDbl (odico : obj) : bool =
   match odico with
   | :? Map<string,double> as d -> true
   | _                          -> false

let testTrue  = testStrDbl (box dctStrDbl)    // this evaluates to true
let testFalse = testStrStr (box dctStrStr)    // this evaluates to false
let testMiscFalse = testStrDbl (box lstMisc)  // evaluates to false
```

However I would like to pattern match on a generic Map of type `Map<'k,'v>` (rather than on a specific type Map like `Map<string,double>`). In pseudo-code :

```
let testGenMap (odico : obj) : bool =
    match odico  with
    | :? Map<'k,'v> as d -> true
    | _                  -> false
```

but it does not work as these would both evaluate to false

```
let testStrDblGen = testGenMap (box dctStrDbl)
let testStrDblGen = testGenMap (box dctStrStr)
```

My question : is there a way to match on a generic `Map<'k,'v>`?

= EDIT =======

Maybe I should have given some extra context. What I am truly after is something like this

```
let findGen (odico : obj) (defVal : 'a) (apply : (Map<'k,'v> -> 'a)) : 'a = 
    match odico with
    | :? Map<'k,'v> as d -> apply d
    | _                  -> defVal // the object is not of the expected type
```

... where I can recover the generic types `'k` and `'v`. In that sense, nilekirk's proposed solution would not work as is.

Comment: This question is asking how do to something that circumvents the type system and which therefore should not be allowed. It does not suggest a deficiency in the type system which would require such a workaround. So the proper approach would be start with the underlying objective of the code. This should be solveable through the type system (or in the case where it is not should be turned into a language suggestion).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no built-in way to pattern match on a generic Map.

What you can do is use reflection and an active pattern:

```
let (|IsMap|_|) (x: obj) =
    if x.GetType().Name.StartsWith("FSharpMap") then Some () else None

let test = function
    | IsMap -> true
    | _ -> false

Map.empty<int,string> |> test // true
[1] |> test // false
```

= EDIT =======

Seeing your edit above, maybe the following will work:

```
let isMap<'k,'v when 'k : comparison> (m: obj) =
    typeof<Map<'k,'v>> = m.GetType()

let findGen odico defVal (apply : Map<'k,'v> -> 'a) =
    if odico |> isMap<'k,'v> then
        odico |> unbox<Map<'k,'v>> |> apply
    else
        defVal

let apply (x: Map<int,string>) = "the apply result"

findGen ([1,"one"] |> Map.ofList) "defVal" apply // "the apply result"
findGen (["one",1] |> Map.ofList) "defVal" apply // "defval"
findGen [1] "defVal" apply // "defval"
```