# F# How to extract keys from a boxed Map object

Tags: reflection, f#

This is a follow-up of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55877793/f-pattern-matching-on-a-generic-type-map/55878543#55878543) and [that post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59242217/f-generic-map-count).

I need to write a function which takes an object (`obj` type) and a key (also an `obj` type), and if the object happens to be a Map, that is any `Map<'k,'v>` then extracts its keys and values.

The difficulty is that I cannot parametrize the function with generic types and that we cannot pattern-match objects on generic types.

I am not familiar with F# Reflection, but I found a way to get the Map's values, once I know its keys. With this example code :

```
module TestItem = 
    open System
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

    // some uninteresting types for this example, could be anything arbitrary
    type Foo = {argF1 : string; argF2 : double; argF3 : bool[]}
    type Bar = {argB1 : string; argB2 : double; argB3 : Foo[]}

    // and their instances
    let foo1 = {argF1 = "foo1"; argF2 = 1.0; argF3 = [| true  |]}
    let foo2 = {argF1 = "foo2"; argF2 = 2.0; argF3 = [| false |]}

    let bar1 = {argB1 = "bar1"; argB2 = 10.0; argB3 = [| foo1 |]}
    let bar2 = {argB1 = "bar2"; argB2 = 20.0; argB3 = [| foo2 |]}

    // a Map type
    type Baz = Map<String,Bar>    
    let baz : Baz = [| ("bar1", bar1); ("bar2", bar2) |] |> Map.ofArray

    let item (oMap : obj) (key : obj) : unit =
        let otype = oMap.GetType()

        match otype.Name with
        | "FSharpMap`2" -> 
            printfn "  -Map object identified"
            let prop  = otype.GetProperty("Item")

            try
                let value = prop.GetValue(oMap, [| key |]) 
                printfn "  -Value associated to key:\n %s" (value.ToString())
            with
            | _             ->  
                printfn "  -Key missing from oMap"
        | _             ->  
            printfn "  -Not a Map object"

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        printfn "#test with correct key"
        let test = item baz "bar1"

        printfn "\n#test with incorrect key"
        let test = item baz "bar1X"

        Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        0 // return exit code 0
```

Running the code above ouputs the following to the Console :

```
#test with correct key
  -Map object identified
  -Value associated to key:
 {argB1 = "bar1";
 argB2 = 10.0;
 argB3 = [|{argF1 = "foo1";
            argF2 = 1.0;
            argF3 = [|true|];}|];}

#test with incorrect key
  -Map object identified
  -Key missing from oMap
```

Now, to solve my problem, I would just need to find a way to extract the keys from the oMap object.

My question : how to complete the code below to return the oMap keys, of type obj[], if oMap is indeed a boxed Map object?

```
module CompleteThis =
    open System
    open Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection

    let keys (oMap : obj) (key : obj) : obj[] =
        let otype = oMap.GetType()

        match otype.Name with
        | "FSharpMap`2" -> 
            printfn "  -Map object identified"

            (* COMPLETE HERE *)
            Array.empty // dummy
        | _             ->  
            printfn "  -Not a Map object"
            Array.empty // return empty array
```

Comment: Matching on types is an improper part of the type system. It's extremely unlikely that you need to do this. Proper F# code outside of the compiler does not use `Microsoft.FSharp.Reflection` or  `GetType()`. These things are exposed for users to allow working around the type system but that was a mistake (.Net's mistake more than F#'s).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you have a typed map `map`, one way of doing this is to iterate over the map using a sequence expression and get the keys using the `Key` property of the `KeyValuePair` that you get:

```
[| for kvp in map -> box kvp.Key |]
```

Reconstructing the code to do this using reflection (in the same way in which you invoke `Item` in your other example) would be a nightmare. A nice trick that you can do is to put this into a generic method:

```
type KeyGetter = 
  static member GetKeys<'K, 'V when 'K : comparison>(map:Map<'K, 'V>) = 
    [| for kvp in map -> box kvp.Key |]
```

Now, you can access the `GetKeys` method via reflection, get the type arguments of your `Map` and use those as `'K` and `'V` of the method, and invoke the method with your `oMap` as an argument:

```
let keys (oMap : obj) : obj[] =
    let otype = oMap.GetType()    
    match otype.Name with
    | "FSharpMap`2" ->          
        typeof<KeyGetter>.GetMethod("GetKeys")
            .MakeGenericMethod(otype.GetGenericArguments())
            .Invoke(null, [| box oMap |]) :?> obj[]
    | _             ->  
        Array.empty
```

This works. However, I should add that I the fact that you actually need to do this is a sign that your system is most likely not exactly well designed, so I would consider changing the design of your application so that you do not need to do this kind of thing. There are, of course, some good reasons for doing something like this, but it should not be too common.

Comment: "There are, of course, some good reasons for doing something like this". I am very skeptical. Can you give any?

Comment: Any kind of entity-generic libraries where the library author doesn't have any knowledge of the types passed in by the user eg. parsers, serializers, db access.

Comment: Yep, what @JSparrow says is pretty much what I was thinking of - automatic DB interfacing or some kind of serialization would be a reasonable place for something like this (but then, you'd probably want a more efficient approach using Reflection.Emit).

Comment: @Tomas Petricek. I wasn't aware of the `KeyValuePair` type and I'll have to spend a bit more time on your Reflection trick to understand it better, but it works well, thanks.
(I have to break down my other comments into a few smaller subsections due to comments size limit).

Comment: 1- On why I seem to circumvent F# type system : I am using [Excel-DNA](https://excel-dna.net/) to write F# user-defined functions (UDFs) and give the Excel's user extra tools to interact with his spreadsheet. One of these tools is a custom dictionary object which the user can _arbitrarily_ define _at runtime_ from any key-value pairs in his sheet.

Comment: 2- Now, as much as I regret it, Excel is not strongly-typed (try the formula `=SUM({1,"Hello World",2,TRUE,3})` in your favourite spreadsheet), and cells are of type double, bool, obj, obj[,] and ExcelErrors (e.g. there's no string type available, string arguments come in as `obj` in Excel-DNA / F# and [need unboxing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56079740/2518338)).

Comment: 3- All that to say that the Excel user can decide the dictionary type (type of its keys and values) _at runtime_ and that there is no reason (*) to limit his ability to create any dictionary (e.g. string to double, double to bool, bool to obj, or indeed string to obj[,] or, why not, string to dictionary object...). 
(*) other, of course, than my own limitations to handle untyped mess in F# later.

Comment: 4- ... hence my attempt to circumvent F# type system using F# Reflection. The day Excel's replacement becomes strongly typed, I'll be the first one to jump ship, but realistically it'll be a while. I'd be interested to know if you think that this use-case could be one of the "good reasons" you mentioned? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Janthelme I don't know enough about Excel DNA to know whether there are any alternatives, but it sounds like this is a kind of application where ugly hacks are necessary. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

This will return the keys as an array of strings.

```
    let keys (oMap : obj) =
        let otype = oMap.GetType()

        match otype.Name with
        | "FSharpMap`2" -> 
            printfn "  -Map object identified"

            (* COMPLETE HERE *)
            let map = oMap :?> Map<string, Bar>
            let keys = map |> Map.toArray |> Array.map fst
            keys
        | _             ->  
            printfn "  -Not a Map object"
            Array.empty // return empty array

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        printfn "#test with correct key"
        let test = item baz "bar1"

        printfn "\n#test with incorrect key"
        let test = item baz "bar1X"

        let keys = keys baz

        Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        0 // return exit code 0
```