# F# Reflection : Passing an Array as Argument to MethodInfo.Invoke

Tags: reflection, f#

In a [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59249632/f-how-to-extract-keys-from-a-boxed-map-object) I was shown how to use F# Reflection to get keys from a *single* boxed Map object, `Map<'k,'v>`, at runtime. I tried to extend the idea and pass an *array* of boxed Map objects, `Map<'k,'v>[]`, but I cannot find a way to extend the original single-object approach to take an array of objects as argument. I came up with a solution which works but doesn't look right. I am looking for a better, more idiomatic way.

In the code below, `keysFromMap` gets an array of keys from a single boxed `Map<'k,'v>` argument; `keysFromMapArray` is my first attempt to do the same from a boxed `Map<'k,'v>[]` argument - but it does not work - and `keysFromMapArrayWithCast` does work, but having to do the downcast at the FromMapArrayWithCast getter level does not seem right.

The error message I get from running keysFromMapArray (test2 commented out) :

```
{System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'Microsoft.FSharp.Collections.FSharpMap`2[System.String,System.Int32][]'.
```

My question : why extending the keysFromMap approach to take an array of Maps argument does not work, and how to fix it so that it does?

Example code:

```
module Example = 
    open System

    let foo1 = [| ("foo11", 11); ("foo12", 12) |] |> Map.ofArray
    let foo2 = [| ("foo21", 21); ("foo22", 22) |] |> Map.ofArray

    type KeyGetter = 
        static member FromMap<'K, 'V when 'K : comparison>(map:Map<'K, 'V>) = 
            [| for kvp in map -> kvp.Key |]

        static member FromMapArray<'K, 'V when 'K : comparison>(maps:Map<'K, 'V>[]) = 
            maps |> Array.map (fun mp -> [| for kvp in mp -> kvp.Key |]) |> Array.concat

        static member FromMapArrayWithCast<'K, 'V when 'K : comparison>(omaps:obj[]) = 
            let typedmaps = [| for omp in omaps -> omp :?> Map<'K, 'V> |]  // -- DOWNCASTING HERE --
            typedmaps |> Array.map (fun mp -> [| for kvp in mp -> kvp.Key |]) |> Array.concat

    let keysFromMap (oMap : obj) : obj[] =
        let otype = oMap.GetType()    
        match otype.Name with
        | "FSharpMap`2" ->          
            typeof<KeyGetter>.GetMethod("FromMap")
                .MakeGenericMethod(otype.GetGenericArguments())
                .Invoke(null, [| box oMap |]) :?> obj[]
        | _             ->  
            Array.empty

    let keysFromMapArray (oMaps : obj[]) : obj[] =
        // skipped : tests to check that oMaps is not empty, and that all elements have the same type...
        let otype = oMaps.[0].GetType()    
        match otype.Name with
        | "FSharpMap`2" ->          

            typeof<KeyGetter>.GetMethod("FromMapArray")
                .MakeGenericMethod(otype.GetGenericArguments())
                .Invoke(null, [| box oMaps |]) :?> obj[] // -- FAILS HERE --
        | _             ->  
            Array.empty

    let keysFromMapArrayWithCast (oMaps : obj[]) : obj[] =
        // skipped : tests to check that oMaps is not empty, and that all elements have the same type...
        let otype = oMaps.[0].GetType()    
        match otype.Name with
        | "FSharpMap`2" ->          

            typeof<KeyGetter>.GetMethod("FromMapArrayWithCast")
                .MakeGenericMethod(otype.GetGenericArguments())
                .Invoke(null, [| box oMaps |]) :?> obj[]
        | _             ->  
            Array.empty

    [<EntryPoint>]
    let main argv =
        printfn "#test1: keys from Map<'k,'v> - works"
        let test = keysFromMap foo1

        // printfn "#test2: keysFromArray from Map<'k,'v>[] - FAILS"
        // let test = keysFromMapArray [| foo1; foo2 |]

        printfn "#test3: keysFromArrayWithCast from obj[] - works"
        let test = keysFromMapArrayWithCast [| foo1; foo2 |]

        Console.ReadKey() |> ignore
        0 // return exit code 0
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the same case as the following:

```
> type K = static member F(x:int[]) = 3
let f x = typeof<K>.GetMethod("F").Invoke(null, [|(x:obj[])|])
f [|2; 3|];;
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Object[]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Int32[]'.
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at <StartupCode$FSI_0002>.$FSI_0002.main@()
Stopped due to error
```

Making the intermediate function generic solves the problem.

```
> type K = static member F(x:int[]) = 3
let f x = typeof<K>.GetMethod("F").Invoke(null, [|(x:'a[])|]) // unconstrained!
f [|2; 3|];;
type K =
  class
    static member F : x:int [] -> int
  end
val f : x:'a [] -> obj
val it : obj = 3
```

This can be applied to `keysFromMapArray`.

```
    let keysFromMapArray (oMaps : 'a[]) : obj[] =
```

Comment: @ 625 Thanks, I'll check when back at my desk. But then why isn't this also needed for keysFromMap, a single object-argument function, which works just fine with the signature `keysFromMap (oMap : obj) : obj[]`)?

Comment: @Janthelme Because value type arrays are not interchangeable with reference type arrays, while covariance is allowed between reference type arrays. On the other hand, value types and reference types (including arrays) can be boxed/unboxed to `obj` just fine.